# Able to connect to SQLEXPRESS2014, but getting Invalid object name error from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, aspxgridview

I am trying to connect to connect to  SQLEXPRESS2014 from Visual Studio webforms application. 
Looks like the connection is being made, but i am getting 
Invalid object name 'HumanResources.Employee'.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'HumanResources.Employee'.

When i query the databse in Management Studio, it returns the result.

I am using AdventureWorks2012 database.
I use this datasource to bind to a Gridview.

aspx page

```
<asp:sqldatasource id="CustomersSource"
    selectcommand="Select [BusinessEntityID], [NationalIDNumber], [LoginID] 
    From [HumanResources.Employee]"
    connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AdvWorksConnection%>" 
    runat="server"/>
```

Connectionstring

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdvWorksConnection" connectionString="data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS2014;
   initial catalog=AdventureWorks2012;persist security info=True; 
   Integrated Security=True;" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Can you tell me where i am doing wrong. Is something wrong with the connection string.

Comment: Can you flip this line: From [HumanResources.Employee]" to From [HumanResources.dbo.Employee]" and tell us the result? Possible issue mapping to schema

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Travis. This worked for me.  [HumanResources].[Employee] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want this:

```
<asp:sqldatasource id="CustomersSource"
    selectcommand="Select [BusinessEntityID], [NationalIDNumber], [LoginID] 
    From [AdventureWorks2012].[HumanResources].[Employee]"
    connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AdvWorksConnection%>" 
    runat="server"/>
```

Whereas, `AdventureWorks2012` is the database, `HumanResources` is the schema, and `Employee` is the table.

NB: You could remove `[AdventureWorks2012].` and the query should still execute, as your connection string explicitly says to use the `AdventureWorks2012` database.

Comment: Thank you.  This works perfect. As you said even if we remove AdventureWorks2012 , it executes fine.